# ADPREP /forestprep fails to verify replication cycle on schema master

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

I have a single domain server running Server 2003 running a 2003 functional level domain. I am trying to add a server 2008 R2 machine to be another domain controller, with the intention of promoting it to be the primary, and taking off the server 2003 machine.

I am required to run adprep /forestprep on the Server 2003 machine. When I run it, it fails with the following errors:

```
Adprep failed to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot.
[Status/Consequence]
The schema is not upgraded.
[User Action]  
Check the log file ADPrep.log in the C:\WINDOWS\debug\adprep\logs\20101109153331 directory for possible cause of failure.

Adprep encountered an LDAP error. 
Error code: 0x32. Server extended error code: 0x2098, Server error message: 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03151D7D, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0
```

I have confirmed that the user account I am using to run ADPREP, mydomain\administrator, is in the Schema Admins, Enterprise Admins, and Domain admins group.

Attempting to figure out what is with the replication, running `repadmin /showrepl`

```
repadmin running command /showrepl against server localhost

Default-First-Site-Name\SERVERNEW
DC Options: IS_GC
Site Options: (none)
DC object GUID: 0657168e-d854-48d8-a40a-dea3e41e6e87
DC invocationID: 0657168e-d854-48d8-a40a-dea3e41e6e87
```

Anyone know how to fix this error? Would raising the domain and forest to a 2003 functional level have any likelihood of working? While just making a new domain from scratch and typing in all the user names and stuff again isn't a deal breaker because we only have about 15 users, it would still be a big pain.

Thanks

Comment: Do you *have* any w2k DCs?

Comment: @Matthew: No I do not. If I don't find a solution in the meantime, I will try raising it, but I will wait until later tonight when no one is using it in case it blows up.

Comment: Did you verify the health of AD first by running a DCDIAG (I usually use the /e /c /v switches) and correcting any issues it finds?

Comment: @Multiverse IT: All tests passed

Comment: Domain and forest are now at 2003 functional levels

Comment: any change in adprep?

Comment: @Matthew: no change

Comment: Have you tried a dcdiag ?

Comment: Well if you had some way of telling what ldap query adprep is using, you could then find out why it is failing auth. Normally I would use some sort of packet-cap or verbose logging. I am not sure if you will be able to do either. If adprep is running on the same server as the ldap what interface do you capture? Loopback?

Answer (score 1):

The adprep error mentions ldap access rights...

> The problem was that local
>   administrators of that child domain
>   did not have any permissions on Group
>   Policy object of the domain
>   controller. By default they should
>   have Full Control. (Admins of root
>   domain did have this permission.) So
>   when local "domain admins" were added
>   in the Security tab of Group Policy,
>   ADPrep /domainprep could run without a
>   problem.

Lifted from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/windowsserveractive_directory/Aug2005/post23809903.asp).

Comment: I found that link earlier, and Domain admins have full control of the Default Domain Policy GPO.

Comment: I have looked for a bit. There doesn't appear to be any more information on that error. All I can think is that the schema is too difference for the 2k8 adprep to work properly. Maybe raising the functional level may help.

Comment: For me it was adding my user to group membership for Owners and Creators of GPO (translated from Polish).